# Why does my script take forever to run?

Tags: unix, grep

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
    echo "Invalid argument count."
    echo "Usage: $0 <dir1> <dir2>"
    exit
fi

ls $1 >> dir1


for file in $2/*
do
        grep $file $dir1
done

rm $dir1
```

I wrote the script above with the intention to print all files that are both in the two directories whose named are passed to the scripts as the arguments.

But when I ran the script, it took forever. (Never finished, actually!)

Does anyone happen to know what I did wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$dir1 is not defined, so grep has only one argument and search $file in standard input. So grep is waiting input and it will wait forever.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to set up a test to be sure, but you never set a value for `$dir1`, you only redirect  `ls` into a file named `dir1`.

So how about

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
    echo "Invalid argument count."
    echo "Usage: $0 <dir1> <dir2>"
    exit
fi

ls $1 >> dir1


for file in $2/*
do
        grep $file dir1
done

rm dir1
```

When I get a script that's just hanging with no obvious, expected output. I kill it and then add the shell debugging features to the script.

Either at the top, like

```
#!/bin/sh -vx
```

Or at any abitrary place in the script where I suspect a problem OR on the second line, i.e.

```
set -vx
```

OR if I'm pretty sure where the problem is, and the above produce a lot of stuff to scroll throught, then I isolate the suspect lines, turning debugging on and off i.e.

```
set -vx
suspect_code
set +vx
```

Finally, I think your problem can be reduced to

```
ls $1 >> dir1
ls $2/* | fgrep -f dir1
```

This has limitations if your files/dirs have spaces, CRs or other nasty stuff embedded. If you have nice clean filenames, it should work.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't any difference in your script and mine. What's the addition/modification that you made?

Comment: I removed the '$' from line `grep $file dir1`. I'm going to make another comment, so check back in a minute. Good luck.

Comment: What's the `v` for? (I know `x` is for debug). Also, what's difference between `grep $file $dir1` and `grep $file dir1` ?

Comment: v = verbose mode, it shows the line or block of code 'as is' before variable expansion is done. You'd need a statement like `dir1=myDir` for `$dir1` to have a value, right? Using `set -vx` you'll see that right away.